# How to insert image in placehold.it

Tags: html

I'm use http://placehold.it to put image size,but I don't know how to insert image,for example :

```
   <img src="image/abc.png" alt="" />
```

and when i use placehod.it as src="https://placehold.it/320x150"

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use placeholder image by just requesting the following URL:

http://placehold.it/300x200

The first parameter defines the width and the second parameter is height.

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
```

Answer (score 3):

http://placehold.it is just provide dummy images to fill up your content. You don't use it to set the image size. Use this:

```
<img src="image/abc.png" style="width:320px;height:150px" alt="" />
```

Comment: You can use both ways, directly like http://placehold.it/300x200 and then style it eventually.